# Is it worth changing <br/> to <br> for moving to Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, javadoc

We are in process of moving from Java 7 to 8. Our source code is littered with `<br/>` tags. We either need to replace them all by `<br>` tags (much fun for 1900 Java projects...) or deactivate the check for strict HMTL 4.0.1.

I heard that Java 9 allows you to create HTML 5 Javadoc which would again allow `<br/>` tags. So when we move on to Java 9 (may 2021 or so...) our Javadoc would become valid again. Under this impression it seems best to just deactivate the Java 8 check. Am I right? Or do I miss something?

Comment: just a thought, how hard would a grep with replace be? well may be just checking out those projects and pushing back... but the process itself would be pretty easy

Comment: @Eugene what if, for some reason, there are `<br/>`s outside the javadocs?

Comment: Can't you generate your javadoc with JDK9 and keep Java 8 for all the rest of the process.

Comment: Question does this also hold for `<br />` - with a space?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I think you can make such a search regex to only find those in the java doc, but certainly a good point

Comment: In our code base there’s a lot of HTML going into Swing components, certainly with <br> tags (with and without slash) in it too. That is, outside Javadoc. In this case removing slashes probably won’t harm, but it still emphasizes @FedericoklezCulloca’s point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with deactivating the check because:

1. There is an intrinsic danger in modifying a large number of source files.
2. In other cases, depending on the rest of the HTML `<br/>` is parsable by XML processors in a polyglot environment, whereas `<br>` would look like an opening tag only.